# Getting List type of class from ParameterizedTypeImpl

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a field of Map I am trying instantiate that looks like this

```
Map<Long, List<MyObj>>
```

The code to convert it is this

```
ParameterizedType targetMapParameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) targetMethodMap.get(targetMethodName).getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
Class<?> mapType = targetMethodMap.get(targetMethodName).getParameterTypes()[0];
if(mapType.isInterface()) {
    newMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
} else {
    try {
        newMap = (Map<Object, Object>) mapType.newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        newMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }
}
Class<?> targetKeyType = null;
Class<?> targetValueType = null;
try {
    targetKeyType = (Class<?>)targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    cce.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    targetValueType = (Class<?>)targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    cce.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is related to this post I read: [ClassCastException While casting List<String> to Class<?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623908/classcastexception-while-casting-liststring-to-class).

```
targetValueType
```

is a ParameterizedTypeImpl object. If I look at the value of that object in debug it looks like java.util.List(MyObj path).

How do "know" that the object is a list progromatically so I can do the conversion?

**Update**

This is an object factory that converts autogenerated domain objects from webservices to DTO domain objects. So the below code is generalized so that it should be able to handle any type of parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following code

```
ParameterizedType targetMapParameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) targetMethodMap.get(targetMethodName).getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
Class<?> mapType = targetMethodMap.get(targetMethodName).getParameterTypes()[0];
if(mapType.isInterface()) {
    newMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
} else {
    try {
        newMap = (Map<Object, Object>) mapType.newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        newMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }
}
Class<?> targetKeyType = null;
Class<?> targetValueType = null;
try {
    targetKeyType = (Class<?>)targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    cce.printStackTrace();
}

if(targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[1] instanceof ParameterizedType) {

ParameterizedType paramTypeImpl = (ParameterizedType) targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
Class<?> containerParam = (Class<?>) paramTypeImpl.getRawType();

if(containerParam.isInstance(new ArrayList<>()) && containerParam.isInterface()) {

    containerParam = new ArrayList<>().getClass();
    }
    targetValueType = containerParam;
} else {
    targetValueType = (Class<?>)targetMapParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}
```

I had to get the raw type of the parameterizedTypeImple object. Then check if it was related to a list and an interface and use that as Class object.

Answer (score 0):

The instantiation should look like this:

```
Map<Long, List<MyObj>> newMap;

...

if(mapType.isInterface()) {
    newMap = new HashMap<Long, List<MyObj>>();
} else {
    try {
        newMap = (Map<Long, List<MyObj>>) mapType.newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        newMap = new HashMap<Long, List<MyObj>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do this though because this needs to be generic.

Comment: @lowlyone ok then you should change the declaration of newMap to `Map newMap;`